# How do I scrape content from a password-protected website in R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

How do I scrape content from a password-protected website in R? I am currently using rvest (open to suggestions), and have tried setting the values of the page's login form using the following:

```
login<-"url"
pgsession<-html_session(login)
pgform<-html_form(pgsession)[[1]]
filled_form<-set_values(pgform, email="*****", password="*****")
submit_form(pgsession, filled_form)
```

But set_values() returns the following error message:
`Error: Unknown field names: email, password`

And the values returned for pgform are:
`<form> '<unnamed>' (GET )`

What am I doing wrong here? Should I be using a different package or command to log into this site?

Comment: If it is password protected, it is probably illegal or forbidden to web scrape it.

Comment: pgform does not contain a email and password field thus the error.  Check to see if there other forms on the page.  Maybe: `html_form(pgsession)[[2]]`

Comment: I tried `html_form(pgsession)[[2]]` and got an out of bound error. The html on the page, for the email input, is: `<input id="id_email" class="text-input" placeholder="" tabindex="2" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none" type="email" aria-label="Email" value="****">`